# Velocity test error with meteor 1.3

Tags: meteor, jasmine, velocity

I'm having an error with Velocity test on Meteor 1.3.1

I'm using sanjo:jasmine package

Here is the error that I got:

```
Using velocity:METEOR@1.2.1_2 as requested (overriding Meteor 1.3.1)

=> Started proxy.

=> Errors prevented startup:

While selecting package versions: error: Conflict: Constraint meteor@1.1.11-modules.4 is not satisfied by meteor 1.1.10.

Constraints on package "meteor":

* meteor@=1.1.10 <- top level

* meteor@1.1.10 <- less 2.5.1

.

.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Zy2.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Could you please edit your question to include the error as text, so that it can be searched more easily?

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time posting a question here. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Velocity does not support Meteor 1.3. See [this post](https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-v1-3-velocity-integration-tests-with-sanjo-jasmine-no-longer-working-after-upgrade-from-1-2-1-to-1-3/20477?u=alon) for a similar issue.